# Modified Shortest Path - no 2 consecutive edges w/ same color

Tags: algorithm

I've actually been thinking about this assigned problem for a while, but I can't get anywhere... I know Bellman-Ford, Dijkstra and Floyd Warshall.

Pretty much it's a standard shortest path problem with V verticies and E edges, each edge with a length L and a color C. They are bidirectional.

The only constraint is that you should find the length of the shortest path without going on 2 consecutive edges with the same color.

Floyd-warshall could work if V was smaller, but V is bounded by (3, 50000).

Any help? thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like Dijkstra's, but keep track of the shortest path *ending in a particular color* to each vertex.

Comment: Thanks I thought this wouldn't run in time but it ended up running in time. I use a map b/c colors could go up to a million

Answer (score 0):

The paper at http://paginas.matem.unam.mx/publicaciones/phocadownloadpap/Preliminares-DF/879.pdf, Shortest H-restricted paths in arc colored digraphs, seems to be using a pretty standard path-finding algorithm, but keeping separate information for each color of each vertex. It is for digraphs, but I guess you can construct a digraph from an undirected graph.